# LEFT JOIN count causing figures to 'square' instead of count?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query re-written to join tables rather than perform subqueries, as I need to lookup around 10 figures and 10 subqueries is having a tad of a performance issue.

**Table names and columns changed for simplicity** *

The query previously did this:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, 
(SELECT COUNT(j1.j_id) FROM jointable1 as j1 WHERE t1.t_employee_id = j1.j_employee_id
    AND t1.t_week_ending = j1.j_week_ending AND j1.j_reason <> 'DNC') as col4,
(SELECT COUNT(j2.j_id) FROM jointable1 as j2 WHERE t1.t_employee_id = j2.j_employee_id
    AND t1.t_week_ending = j2.j_week_ending) as col5
FROM table1 as t1
GROUP BY t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3;
```

I have re-written it like this:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, COUNT(j1.j_id) as col4, COUNT(j2.o_id) as col5
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN jointable1 as j1 ON (t1.t_employee_id = j1.j_employee_id
    AND t1.t_week_ending = j1.j_week_ending)
    AND j1.j_reason = <> 'DNC'
GROUP BY t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3;
```

The problem is that the values that return for col4 and col5 in the top example, are fine. Let's say they return 7 and 8.

```
+------+------+------+------+--+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
|    1 |    0 |    0 |   34 |  |
|    0 |    3 |    3 |    9 |  |
|    7 |    1 |    0 |    2 |  |
|    3 |    2 |    2 |    9 |  |
|    4 |    1 |    0 |    4 |  |
|    1 |   11 |    1 |    4 |  |
|    5 |    2 |    5 |   21 |  |
|    2 |    3 |    0 |    3 |  |
|    2 |    3 |    0 |    2 |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
```

But in the bottom query, they return as squared or multiplied by themself. So 7 becomes 49 and 8 becomes 64.

```
+------+------+------+------+--+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
|    1 |    0 |    0 | 1156 |  |
|    0 |    3 |    3 |   81 |  |
|    7 |    1 |    0 |   16 |  |
|    3 |    2 |    2 |   81 |  |
|    4 |    1 |    0 |   16 |  |
|    1 |   11 |    1 |   16 |  |
|    5 |    2 |    5 |  441 |  |
|    2 |    3 |    0 |    9 |  |
|    2 |    3 |    0 |    4 |  |
+------+------+------+------+--+
```

I can't tell if it's the LEFT JOIN or something missing from the GROUP BY function, but any help in rectifying would be great, **or** any help in re-writing to an even more efficient way would be also great.

Comment: Can you show us some sample table data and the expected result? (Formatted text, not images.) Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing the query with `outer apply`. This will be more efficient. Also, you will not get correct counts for `col5` from your second query. You need the count of the rows where `j_reason` is not `DNC` for `col4`, and all of them for `col5`.

```
SELECT  t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, c4.col4, c5.col5
FROM    table1 as t1
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  COUNT(j1.j_id) col4
    FROM    jointable1 as j1 
    WHERE   t1.t_employee_id = j1.j_employee_id
    AND     t1.t_week_ending = j1.j_week_ending 
    AND     j1.j_reason <> 'DNC'
)c4
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  COUNT(j2.j_id) col5
    FROM    jointable1 as j2 
    WHERE   t1.t_employee_id = j2.j_employee_id
    AND     t1.t_week_ending = j2.j_week_ending
)c5
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Initially, it performed slower when retrieving the query in SSMS, but within the software/application it's over 55-60% faster than before. Really appreciate this!

Answer (score 2):

Number of rows may increase if you have multiple matching records in your `JOINS` which can give you incorrect results when you use aggregate function like `COUNT`. You need to use `COUNT` with `DISTINCT` like following.

```
 SELECT   t1.col1, 
          t1.col2, 
          t1.col3, 
          Count(DISTINCT j1.j_id) AS col4, 
          Count(DISTINCT j1.o_id) AS col5 
FROM      table1                  AS t1 
LEFT JOIN jointable1              AS j1 
ON        t1.t_employee_id = j1.j_employee_id 
AND       t1.t_week_ending = j1.j_week_ending 
AND       j1.j_reason = <> 'DNC' 
GROUP BY  t1.col1, 
          t1.col2, 
          t1.col3;
```

**Note:** In your query you are using alias name `j2` which is not set anywhere, you need to correct it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Better to do the counts in subqueries that can work them out for all combinations, then join to those results now you know you'll only be joining to *one* row from each subequery.

You problems come when you join to multiple tables in a 1-many fashion. If you have two 1-2 associations and join to both, you get *4* rows, not *2*.

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, j1.Cnt, /* same for j2 */
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN (select j_employee_id,j_week_ending,COUNT(j_id) AS Cnt
     from jointable1
     where j_reason <> 'DNC'
     group by j_employee_id,j_week_ending) j1
ON (t1.t_employee_id = j1.j_employee_id
    AND t1.t_week_ending = j1.j_week_ending)
/* Same again for j2 */
/* Don't need GROUP BY out here at all now? */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    t1.col3, 
    cnt.col4,
    cnt.col5
FROM table1 as t1
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT j1.j_employee_id
            ,j1.j_week_ending
            ,SUM(CASE WHEN j1.j_reason <> 'DNC' AND j1.j_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as col4
            ,COUNT(j1.j_id) as col5
        FROM jointable1 as j1
        GROUP BY j1.j_employee_id, j1.j_week_ending
    ) cnt ON t1.t_employee_id = cnt.j_employee_id
        AND t1.t_week_ending = cnt.j_week_ending
GROUP BY t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3;
```